# Iterator cpp, operator overloading

Tags: c++, oop, iterator, overloading, operator-keyword

I have written an operator= for my input iterator and i get error which says "error: extra qualification on member 'operator='"

Here is piece of code:

```
input_iterator& input_iterator::operator=(const input_iterator &customerSource){
     if (this == &customerSource){
        return *this;
     }
     innerIter = customerSource.innerIter;

     return *this;
  }
```

Comment: Though experts in the language can divine what you did wrong using their experience (e.g. answerers below), there is actually no reproducible testcase here. In particular, the actual cause of the problem is _not_ included in the code sample. I don't see this question helping anyone else in the future. Therefore, voted to close as not enough information.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining a member function inside of class definition. In that case `class_name::` should not be specified.

Replace to this

```
input_iterator& operator=(const input_iterator &customerSource){
     if (this == &customerSource){
        return *this;
     }
     innerIter = customerSource.innerIter;

     return *this;
  }
```

Or move function definition out from the class.